# Reading console input: IOException

Tags: java, input, console-application, ioexception

I created a method to read console input as integer

```
public static Integer readInteger() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I had to include `throws IOException` but in this case when could possibly be an IOException thrown as long as System.in is not closed?

Comment: How is Java supposed to know that in this one special use case `IOException` cannot be thrown? In fact it's not the case that it cannot be, but even if it were there is no way to know. `readLine` is declared to throw an `IOException`.

Comment: What I meant was are there any common cases I should keep in mind in my situation where this exception could be thrown. Like before reading a file try to check whether it exists to avoid an exception. Something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is a "heavy" topic in java.

Most java programmers now a days agree, checked exceptions are stupid and redundant and should not exist.

In your case, what if it is closed? the compiler does not know when will the program run, neither does he not know on what environment he is going to run.

What if, the current user that runs the program does not have permission to write to the console?

I can keep going but i think you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with David Limkys.

The  Class IOException signals that an I/O exception of some sort has occurred. 
This class is the general class of exceptions produced by failed or interrupted I/O operations.